# Google Drive API File Sharing - Commenter ("additional role") no longer works

Tags: google-drive-api

A month or so ago (October 2014?) I was able to set permissions on a google file to share it with another google account, and I added the permission with an authenticated request like this:

```
service.Permissions.Insert(new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Permission() 
{ Value = user.EMail, Type = "user", Role = "reader", AdditionalRoles = new List<string>() { "commenter" } }, file.Id);
```

It worked fine...until today. Today I get the following response:
Bad Request. User message: "Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing."

Even when I try to use their demo I get the same response:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

The only posts I've seen about this were from 2011 when the commenter role was not working, so I wonder if they accidentally broke the API for the commenter role.

**Update**
The problem was that it was a form that I was trying to share.

Answer (score 1):

This operation worked properly for me from the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.permissions.insert?fileId=ENTER%20FILE%20ID&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522role%2522%253A%20%2522reader%2522%252C%250A%20%20%2522type%2522%253A%20%2522user%2522%252C%250A%20%20%2522value%2522%253A%20%2522ENTER%20EMAIL%2522%252C%250A%20%20%2522additionalRoles%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%255B%2522commenter%2522%250A%20%20%255D%250A%257D&). It sounds like there's a restriction on your sharing. This may be the case if you are not the owner of the file or if your Google Apps domain restricts sharing files outside the domain.

The `writersCanShare` attribute of the [file representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) should tell you if editors can add new permissions.

The `domainSharingPolicy` returned by [about.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) should tell you if the user is restricted from sharing files outside the domain.

Comment: Where can I check that the "Google Apps domain restricts sharing outside the domain?"

Comment: updated answer to include solutions for checking restrictions at the file and account level.

Comment: DomainSharingPolicy is set to "allowed" and WritersCanShare is set to true

Comment: I tried with different files - it works with one but not the other. Is there a file setting that would affect this? Even when sharing on GDrive, it allows me to only share with "Can Edit" for that file. With the file that works it allows me to choose "Can Comment" and "Can View" as well. This must be some file setting that I can't find

Comment: What type of file is it? I'm not sure all file types support comments.

Comment: That must be it - it happened to be a form that I was trying to share. I wonder if there is a list of types that can be shared as commenter.